# Swift Sqlite Lite Insert From On Remote Notification

Tags: swift, sqlite

I am attempting to call a SQLite insert method from the AppDelegate.swft method didReceiveRemoteNotiication. I have the following code :

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        let db = try! Connection()
        //try db.run(users.insert(email <- "xxx@gmail.com", name <- userInfo))

        print(userInfo)

    }
```

I want to insert the string "userInfo" when the remote notification is received, however when I attempt to run the commented code I get "Command failed due to signal: Abort trap: 6" error.

I was able to achieve this with my android version of the app, my question is how can I make this work for Swift 3.0?

Comment: are you talking about `userInfo` which is the name of the dictionary payload which is passed into this method? Or literally you want to hard-code a string which will just be "userInfo"?

Comment: userInfo is the payload from the push notification that I want inserted into the table.

Comment: So I don't know how your data model is setup, but that `userInfo` payload can be a huge dictionary full of lots of key-value-pairs, it's not just going to be one string.